# conditional insert in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to insert some data in table if count is more than 10. My example code is here

```
IF EXISTS (select * from tbl1) 
BEGIN
   select e.UserId, count(*) as [Registrations], 'qq' = 
       case 
        when count(*) < 10 then 'less than 10'
        when count(*) > 10 then 'more than 10' 
       end
    from tbl1 as e group by e.UserId
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   select * from tbl2
END
```

How can I put `begin insert tbl2 values(1, '2013-01-31 19:08:19.847') end` when `count(*)` is more than 10?

Directly insert isn't allowed I can't assign insert to variable

[image: that's my result of count(*)]

that's my result of count(*)

Comment: What `count(*)` are you referring to?  Sample data and desired results are helpful.

Comment: @George Try following  `IF (select COUNT(*) from tbl1) > 10`

Comment: @GordonLinoff count(*) is whole row. for example it returns 37
1
2
69
22 etc.

Comment: @George `Count(*)` is an integer value. can you explain what you mean by `whole row` ?

Comment: Your select inside of 'true condition', should have 'HAVING COUNT(*) > 10' clause if I understood correctly what you asking for

Comment: @tchelidze I've added picture

Comment: Yep, google for HAVING COUNT(*)  clause, that's what you looking for

Comment: @Veljko89 yeah that's it thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Veljko89 wrote - you can use HAVING after the GROUP BY and select this into a temp table. You can then use this temp table to decide when/what to insert into your second table.